# Making double JOIN to the same table in SQL, performance problem

Tags: sql, join, relation

I'm having a problem with a particular issue but I will generalize because it's, really, a general problem.

I have (summarizing) the following diagram

```
Main_Table                            Doctors
--------------                        ---------------
PK ID                                 PK ID_Doctor
   ID_Prescribing_Doctor                 Name
   ID_Performer_Doctor
```

Then, in a query, I have to JOIN Main_Table with Doctors in order to show both names (from Prescribing and Performers doctors) in each row.

So:

```
SELECT MT.ID, PRES_DOC.Name, PERF_DOC.Name
FROM [SCHEME].Main_Table as MT
LEFT JOIN [SCHEME].Doctors AS PRES_DOC ON MT.ID_Prescribing_Doctor = 
                                          PRES_DOC.ID_Doctor
LEFT JOIN [SCHEME].Doctors AS PERF_DOCON MT.ID_Prescribing_Doctor = 
                                         PERF_DOC.ID_Doctor
```

The query is working fine. I'm retrieving all the data I wish.
However, there's a performing problem.

Main_Table table has (mostly) 10.000.000 rows.
Doctors table has (mostly) 20.000 rows.

When it does the JOINs it takes its time.

I've also tried to create a view with the fields:

```
ID_Prescriber | Name_Prescriber | ID_Performer | Name_Performer
```

and make one JOIN.

However, considering the table has almost 20 000, the view retrieves nearly 400 000 000 rows. So the performance get worse.

I would like to know if there's a way to achieve this without the need to make two JOINS to the same table.

All answers I read in other issues are about making two JOINs.

**MORE INFORMATION**

Considering the answers given, I'm afraid I did not explain myself clearly. The aim of this thread is not to look for a solution for a particular problem but to know news alternatives solutions to some scenarios (like the one proposed above) where you have to create two joins to the same table.

Summarizing, **I'd like to know if there's another way to solve that kind of problem only in order to have a range of solutions and then, given the case, apply the best solution.**

The reason I raised that specific problem is to give some context and not be an empty question. But solving that particular problem is not the issue.

Comment: You are retrieving 10,000,000 rows.  That takes time.

Comment: And the view shouldn't return any more rows than the query, if you've got the same joins.

Comment: **Your query does not have a filtering predicate/condition**. That means you are retrieving all the rows of the main table with the accompanying rows from the secondary one. That is 10 million rows. It's bound to be slow by definition. I assume it's for batch processing, since doing this online doesn't make too much sense, right?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I do not retrieve ALL the rows (everytime) it applys lots of filtering and groups. That's why I said 'I will generalize'. Despite the context, I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid creating two JOINS.

Comment: @GreatNews The problem is not the joins, those are simple primary key lookups. It's likely a lack of proper indexes on whatever you're filtering and grouping by. We would need to see an example of the "lots of filtering and groups" and the output of `explain` to say more.

Comment: Thanks you all for answering. I added more information to the question because I think I didn't explain myself clearly. Please, see at "MORE INFORMATION"